# How can I re-sort records for my text file?

Tags: batch-file

Morning guys,

I have a text file like this (original.txt):

```
AAAA
BBBB
CCCC
DDDD
EEEE
FFFF
```

I need a file like this (result.txt):

```
AAAA BBBB
CCCC DDDD
EEEE FFFF
```

Could you please help me with that by batch?

Thanks,

Comment: This is Windows, right?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: This is a code request, which is clearly off-topic here! Please share your efforts by providing a [mcve]! Read the [tour] and learn [ask] here!

Comment: @Gnudiff, yes, tha [tag:bat-file] tag implies Windows (unless the OP is using MS-DOS, but I guess not since it's from the 1980s)...

Comment: I know I've seen this exact scenario asked and answered here before, please search this site using the search box, _(tip, use [batch-file] searchterm)_.

Answer (score 2):

Although you did not show any own efforts; I provide an answer this time. Make sure you post your coding attempts next time!

There are two methods I can think of: using [`for /F`](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) to read the file, and using [input redirection (`<`)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) and [`set /P`](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html).

---

Here is the approach using `for /F`:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
> "result.txt" (
    set "LEFT="
    for /F "usebackq delims=" %%I in ("original.txt") do (
        if defined LEFT (
            echo/!LEFT! %%I
            set "LEFT="
        ) else (
            set "LEFT=%%I"
        )
    )
)
endlocal
```

---

And here is the other approach:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F %%I in ('^< "original.txt" find /C /V ""') do set /A "COUNT=%%I/2"
< "original.txt" > "result.txt" (
    for /L %%I in (1,1,%COUNT%) do (
        set /P LEFT="" & set /P RIGHT=""
        echo/!LEFT! !RIGHT!
    )
)
endlocal
```